# mongoimport imports csv file disordered

Tags: mongodb, shell, csv

I have a 23k rows csv file. When i use mongoimport from shell or import from mongochef somehow it imports with wrong order.

for example i have

```
a;b;c;(header)
1;1;1;
2;2;2;
3;3;3;
```

csv file. when i import it from shell or mongochef and then .find() it result is ;

```
a|b|c
1;1;1;
3;3;3;
2;2;2;
```

any help would be great. Here is my shell command for import ;

```
mongoimport -d local -c test --type csv --file "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Example Datasets\abc.csv" --headerline --ignoreBlanks
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using [--maintainInsertionOrder](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--maintainInsertionOrder) option.

As the docs say:

> If specified, mongoimport inserts the documents in the order of their
>   appearance in the input source, otherwise mongoimport may perform the
>   insertions in an arbitrary order

Also notice that the `find` default ordering is the [natural order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#return-in-natural-order) that doesn't guarantee returning results by the insertion order. So what I usually do is sorting by the `_id` field.